# Как задать сложный медиа запрос под нужный телефон?

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Подскажите, как написать правильное css медиа выражение под устройства 375х812 и 375х667 (Iphone 7). Мне по умолчанию необходимо что б у класса .bl_counter {top: 270px;} Но при этом для Iphone 7 должно быть .bl_counter {top: 330px;}

Я пробую писать 

`@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) { .bl_counter {
top: 270px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) and (max-height: 670px){
/// Iphone 7
.bl_counter {
top: 330px;
}
}`

Но это не работает правильно

*В @media only screen and (max-width: 390px) { У меня много других стилей }

Comment: Зачем Вы то что должно быть по умолчанию `.bl_counter {top: 270px;}`, пишите в медиа запрос?

Comment: высоту не надо писать ...

Comment: Я не очень корректно выразился. "по умолчанию", это в понимании для всех нормальных смартфонов, при разрешении меньше 390px (Но не для яблофонов)

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {.bl_counter {top: 270px;}}`
`@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {.bl_counter {top: 330px;}}`
В чем проблема?

Comment: В том проблема, что нижнее правило переопределяет верхнее. Для Iphone 7 
 всё становиться хорошо, для всех остальных устройств ломается. Ещё раз (ОБА устройства имеют ширину дисплея 375 px, только высота разная, и это важно) У меня класс элемента на position:absolute повешен, и всё ломаеться если не правильно работает

Comment: У вас первое медиавыражение применяется ко всем устройствам с шириной вьюпорта меньше `390px` и любой высотой. А второе — ко всем устройствам с шириной вьюпорта меньше `390px` и высотой меньше `670px`. Не важно, iPhone это, или любой другой телефон. Вы можете в медиавыражении указать просто `height` вместо `max-height`, либо `aspect-ratio`, но это относится только к размеру вьюпорта, если «Android-телефон» окажется с таким же — то применятся свойства, которые вы пишите для iPhone 7. [Тут можно узнать больше](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).